# Styling button click text

Tags: html, css

When you click an button HTML button, button goes inwards hence making the text inside the button move downwards slightly. My question is, **how can I stop the button changing (going inwards) when it is clicked?**

I hope you can understand my question.

Comment: What's your html and css for the button you're asking about? It's usually to do with borders, padding, margins; but without seeing what's happening with your CSS, I've no way to know what to suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have done whatever you like with the border etc., just put a span inside the button around the text like so:

`<button class="button" type="submit"><span class="buttonspan">Blah</span></button>`

Then the CSS becomes:

```
button {position:relative; width:40px; height:20px /* set whatever width and height */}

buttonspan {
height: 30px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Making sure to set the span absolute and the button relative.. works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Most cross browser friendly and simple answer is probably to replace it with an image - this will give you the most control as all browsers treat buttons differently.. even if you were to try a border: 0 style, the text in the button may still move down in some browsers.